# SyntaxError: missing : after property javascript

Tags: javascript, object, syntax

I want to use the getBarcodeImage(Imageid) function inside this barcode object to scan a barcode image like this

var code = Barcode.getBarcodeImage(Image);

but i get the syntax error `SyntaxError: missing : after property` . I'm pasting the code here . what changes do i have to do to make it work.

```
var Barcode = {
    var UPC_SET;
    UPC_SET = {
      3211: "0",
      2221: "1",
      2122: "2",
      1411: "3",
      1132: "4",
      1231: "5",
      1114: "6",
      1312: "7",
      1213: "8",
      3112: "9"
    };
    getBarcodeFromImage: function(imgOrId) {
        //some code here
          return code;
      }
}
```

Comment: your syntax is incorrect completely.

Comment: can you send jsfiddle link? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Narrow it down for us. This is too much to expect people to look at for something as simple as a syntax error.

Comment: @ChrisHayes : sorry , I edited it .

Answer (score 1):

when setting properties for an object, you don't use the `var` keyword, = sign, or use a semi-colon.

```
var UPC_SET;
UPC_SET = ...
```

should be

```
UPC_SET : { 
  /* your UPC_SET definition*/
},
```

Comment: @chaithu whatever answer you found most useful, don't forget to accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

When defining an object you need to use `x = { key: value, key: value };` format, but you used `x = { statement; key: value }`

```
var Barcode = {
    var UPC_SET;
    UPC_SET = {
      3211: "0",
      2221: "1",
      2122: "2",
      1411: "3",
      1132: "4",
      1231: "5",
      1114: "6",
      1312: "7",
      1213: "8",
      3112: "9"
    };
```

should be

```
var Barcode = {
    UPC_SET: {
      3211: "0",
      2221: "1",
      2122: "2",
      1411: "3",
      1132: "4",
      1231: "5",
      1114: "6",
      1312: "7",
      1213: "8",
      3112: "9"
    },
```

Also, make sure all your braces are closed properly and that the last one is `'};` so it completes the object definition statement.